# Availability of bidictionary structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'm facing a case in my application where I need a bidirectional dictionary data structure, that means a kind of NSDictionary where your can retrieve a key with a value and a value with a key (all values and keys are unique).

Is there such a kind of data structure in C / ObjectiveC ?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, just adding both k=>v and v=>k to the same NSDictionary should solve the problem...?

Comment: Which bidictionary are you talking about in C#? (It's not in C# itself, as that's just a language - but I don't know of a bidirectional dictionary in the .NET framework either.)

Comment: Always a pleasure to see @JonSkeet on iOS topics.

Comment: @JackyBoy: Oh I've got not chance of actually *answering* the question - I'd just like the OP to be clearer in the question itself.

Comment: I think I was wrong about bi dictionary (an intern in my company told me that this feature was available in C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a `NSDictionary`:

> allKeysForObject: Returns a new array containing the keys
>   corresponding to all occurrences of a given object in the dictionary.
>
> - (NSArray *)allKeysForObject:(id)anObject Parameters anObject The value to look for in the dictionary. Return Value A new array
>     containing the keys corresponding to all occurrences of anObject in
>     the dictionary. If no object matching anObject is found, returns an
>     empty array.
>
> Discussion Each object in the dictionary is sent an isEqual: message
>   to determine if it’s equal to anObject.

And:

> objectForKey: Returns the value associated with a given key.
>
> - (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey Parameters aKey The key for which to return the corresponding value. Return Value The value associated with
>     aKey, or nil if no value is associated with aKey.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the suboptimal time complexity - which is linear. For large containers, the performance may become too bad. The Cocoa frameworks do not have a "bidirectional" container with constant or logarithmic time complexity (boost has a [Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)).

Comment: That's up to the dev to decide if it's worth using or not.

Comment: That's true. For use cases with a few elements (say, less than hundreds) this probably wouldn't hurt overall performance.

Comment: I am quite sure you head this before: `Premature optimisation is the root of all evil`..

Comment: You again are correct!  Nonetheless, take this statement with a grain of salt and also consider the 80/20 rule. This means in this context: if you can achieve 80% better performance by adding 20% additional development time, just do it. This also means, don't fall into the habit to not care about performance, rather try to understand the implications, and balance effort and outcome. ;)

Comment: Didn't said I don't care about performance, those are your own words. Different approaches should be consider according to a devs needs. Does it make sense to implement the wrapper around the C++ container (again, your own words) with 50 to 100 records inside the `NSDictionary`? Probably not.

Comment: Don't guess, measure. I didn't state the performance _is_ bad, too. I merely said: <see first comment>

Comment: I was already thinking about a similar solution but I didn't figure that such a method already exist. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the answer is No.

As a workaround you may create a helper class which manages two dictionaries.

Another approach is to create a thin wrapper around C++ container which implement this: boost's [Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

When using ARC and Objective-C objects as values or keys in C++ containers, they will handle NSObjects quite nicely. That is, they take care of memory management as you would expect - and you even get "exception safety" for free. Additionally, C++ standard containers are also a tad faster, use less memory, and provide more options to optimize (e.g. custom allocators).